# I'm trying to update a display score. Why is the score increment appending to the displayed score rather than adding to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a Unity game scene that seems to correctly pass a score to a quiz scene. I'm trying to reward a correct answer in the quiz scene with the points assigned to an integer variable, pointsForCorrectQuizAnswer. For example, if a player begins the quiz with 1000 points, and pointsForCorrectQuizAnswer = 250, the new score should display as 1250, but instead it displays as 1000250, despite my attempt to convert the value of the int pointsForCorrectQuizAnswer to a string.

My code:

```
public class AnswerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool isCorrect = false;
public QuizManager quizManager;

public int pointsForCorrectQuizAnswer = 250; // Points awarded for correctly answering a multiple choice quiz question.


public void Answer()
{
    if(isCorrect)
    {
        Debug.Log("Correct answer.");
        quizManager.Correct();

        quizManager.TxtScore.text += pointsForCorrectQuizAnswer.ToString();
        // quizManager.TxtScore.text += 250.ToString();

    }
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

EDIT: Here's what works now as per John Wu's answer below:

```
public class AnswerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool isCorrect = false;
public QuizManager quizManager;

public int pointsForCorrectQuizAnswer = 250; // Points awarded                   for correctly answering a multiple choice quiz question.


public void Answer()
{
    if(isCorrect)
    {
        Debug.Log("Correct answer.");
        quizManager.Correct();

        var oldScore = int.Parse(quizManager.TxtScore.text);
        var newScore = oldScore + pointsForCorrectQuizAnswer;
        quizManager.TxtScore.text = newScore.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` operator for string means [concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings#:%7E:text=You%20concatenate%20strings%20by%20using,occurs%20only%20at%20run%20time.&text=The%20C%23%20examples%20in%20this,inline%20code%20runner%20and%20playground.), not addition (not all strings are numbers that can be added).

You need to convert the string to an integer in order to add to it.

```
var oldScore = int.Parse(quizManager.TxtScore.Text);
var newScore = oldScore + pointsForCorrectQuizAnswer;
quizManager.TxtScore.Text = newScore.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense. I just made two capitalization changes to your solution above in the edit to my question:                                                                                   var oldScore = int.Parse(quizManager.TxtScore.text);
var newScore = oldScore + pointsForCorrectQuizAnswer;
quizManager.TxtScore.text = newScore.ToString();